# How to increase the value of a specific array index of a dynamic array?

Tags: c#, list, frequency

I am trying to create a dynamic array which will store the frequency of a string. I have converted and placed the string into list. Added values to the integer list. But can't find a way to increase the default values in the list.

```
List<int> size = new List<int>();

List<char> frequency = new List<char>();

frequency = line.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < frequency.Count; i++)
{
      size.Insert(i, 0);
}
foreach (char t in frequency)
{
     size.Add(new int(1, (int)t));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So… you want a dictionary with default values, then? Or something like this?

```
Dictionary<char, int> frequencies = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach(char c in line) {
    if(frequencies.ContainsKey(c)) {
        frequencies[c]++;
    } else {
        frequencies.Add(c, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to store the frequency of characters of a string so that I can use it to write a huffman code. Problem is I can't increase the value of the members of List<int> size

Answer (score 2):

You can get the character frequency into a dictionary structure using LINQ. This assumes that case doesn't matter so `c == C`. but you can change that by remove the `Char.ToUpper()` call.

```
List<String> lines = new List<string>() { "This is", "my", "sentence" };

var charFreq = String.Join("", lines).GroupBy(x => Char.ToUpper(x))
                                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Output for the above `lines` List would be

```
T, 2
H, 1
I, 2
S, 3
 , 1
M, 1
Y, 1
E, 3
N, 2
C, 1
```

Comment: I just want to store the frequency of characters of a string so that I can use it to write a huffman code. Problem is I can't increase the value of the members of List<int> size

Comment: What do you mean increase the values? Increase the values by what amount?

Comment: I just want to store the freuquency. that's why i need to increase values by any amount

Comment: The method above automatically calculates the frequency for you. If you want to manually update it you can do `charFreq["T"] = 50` to change the value of `T`.